# If two cells match, return value from third- one of the "matching" cells is vertically merged

Tags: indexing, merge, excel-formula, excel-2011

I have a contact list from hell that needs cleaning up.  The basic problem is this: the company name is merged vertically and there multiple rows of information for each company (with blank cells everywhere).

[Screenshot of Excel Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH4LV.png)

[image]

I have created a second sheet and was successful in using a formula I found on stack overflow for getting the data from the 2nd column (where the data was on the top of 3 rows):

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!D:D,MATCH(A4,'Sheet1'!A:A,0))
```

However, the same formula doesn't work when the needed data is on the second row.

I have thought about trying to unmerge column A, then duplicating the data from the merged cell to each unmerged cell.  But I'm afraid that having 3 matching cells will return blanks with the formula above.

*I am not a programmer in the least, but I've found stack overflow very helpful for working with Excel.  Thanks for your patience with me and I very much appreciate any help you could give.

Comment: Are the always one row down? If so then simply `=INDEX('Sheet1'!D:D,MATCH(A4,'Sheet1'!A:A,0)+1)` will pull the value from column D, 1 row down from where the match is found.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner.  I suppose I didn't give a great example- The email address is not always in the second row of the three.  I aprreciate the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

A single sample is not really enough to explain the issue, but the following might help, where the single example is highlighted:

[image: SO36946247 example]

ColumnA is after unmerging. The formula in D1 (copied across to E1 and D1:E1 then copied down to suit) is:

```
=TRIM(IF($A1<>"",B1&" "&B2&" "&B3,""))
```